# OrientDB: connected components OSQL query

Tags: orientdb, connected-components

Does anybody know how to compute the connected components of a graph with an OrientDB query? 
I'm trying to replicate what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497707/get-connected-graphs-in-neo4j-by-using-cypher-query) but I'm missing something similar to a REDUCE operator for collections.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query

```
SELECT distinct(traversedElement(0)) 
FROM (TRAVERSE both('ManagedBy') FROM Employee)
```

Returned me the right result. At the beginning I could not understand why but then I figured out that the default strategy used in TRAVERSE is [DFS](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Java-Traverse.html#traversing-strategies) that's why we can rely on taking the first node of each traversal as a representative for its connected component.