# OrientDB: Find Connected Components Values during the visit

Tags: orientdb, connected-components

I have schema with 3 main classes: Transaction , Address and ValueTx(Edge).

I am trying to find connected components within a range of time.

Now I am doing this query based on this one ( [OrientDB: connected components OSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654067/orientdb-connected-components-osql-query)) :

```
SELECT distinct(traversedElement(0)) from ( TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from (select * from Transaction where height >= 402041 and height <= 402044))
```

And this returns the rid of the 'head' of each trasversal and from it doing another DFS I can get every node and edge of the connected component I want to search about.

How can I, using the query above, also get the number of the transactions within the connected component and also the sum of their values? (The value of a tx is a property of the class Transaction)

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT distinct(traversedElement(0)) as head, count(Transaction), sum(valueTot) from ( TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from (select * from Transaction where height >= 402041 and height <= 402044)) group by head
```

But of course is not working. I get only one row with the last head and the sum of all the transactions.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is an example of what I'm looking for:

[Connected Transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCTYu.png)

Every transaction there is within the same range of height:
Using my query ( the first one in my post) I get the rid of the first node of each group of transaction that are linked through several addresses.
example:

```
#15:27
#15:28
#15:30
#15:34
#15:35
#15:36
#15:37
#15:41
#15:47
#15:53
```

What I'm trying to get is a list of every first node with the **total number of transactions** (not addresses only the transaction) of the group it belongs to and the **sum of the value of every Transaction** (stored in valueTot inside the class transaction.

Edit2:
 This is the dataset where I am making the tests: 
The main problem is that I have a lot of data and the approach I was trying before (from every rid I make a different sql query) it's quite slow, I hope there is a faster way. 
Edit3:
This is an updated sample db: [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/enugrjir0mr6sab/BlockChainBK.gz?dl=0)
(note, it's way larger than the other)

```
select head, sum(valueTot) as valueTot, count(*) as numTx,sum(miner) as minerCount from (SELECT *,traversedElement(0) as head from ( TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from (select * from Transaction where height >= 0 and height <= 110000 ) while ( @class = 'Address' or (@class = 'Transaction' and height >= 0 and height <= 110000 )) ) where @class = 'Transaction' ) group by head
```

This query on my system takes around one minute, also if I limit the result set, so I think the problem maybe in the internal query that selects the transactions that isn't using the indexes... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you post a little example of your graph ?

Comment: I posted an update with a picture hoping it is more clear, let me know if you still need clarifications.

Comment: Hi, could you add the schema (Classes with properties) as I can reproduce your environment and do some tests? Tnx

Comment: or if you can share an export of a small test db it would be perfect

Comment: @IvanMainetti I shared my test db, I hope you can help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
select @rid, $a[0].sum as sumValueTot ,$a[0].count as countTransaction from Transaction 
let $a = ( select sum(valueTot),count(*) from (TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from $parent.$current) where @class="Transaction")
where height >= 402041 and height <= 402044
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time, sadly the query it's really slow and at the end the results are not the expected one: I get some repeated results(sum and count) with different rids.
But the main issue it's the speed, it's way slower (5-10 times) than just doing a single query for every group.

Comment: So after studying better the results of the query (that takes around 9 minutes on my dataset of around 40k edges) I saw that I just get the result for every Transaction of the db (around 4k). I didn't manage to fix it.  Maybe also for this reason is really slow? 
I just assumed that if listing the origin of every group is really fast, also counting them would, am I wrong?

Comment: @FrancescoMoca I think that the solution of Ivan Mainetti is correct, 
to increase the speed you can put an index(SB-Tree) on the field height

Answer (score 0):

is this what are you looking for?

```
select head, sum(valueTot), count(*) from (SELECT *,traversedElement(0) as head from ( TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from (select * from Transaction where height >= 402041 and height <= 402044)) where @class = "Transaction") group by head
```

Comment: Sadly after adding more datas I realized my idea was wrong :/.
The traverse of course isn't stopping on the transaction outside the given range of course, so the result is very different from what I need.
I think I need to use the while clause on the trasversal but I can't figure out how.
When the visit meets an address it should check all the next transaction and only continue the visit on the transactions where the height is inside the given range),
So I should have a while in the traverse checking for the range  and return only the correct transactions.
 Any Idea?

Comment: Hi @FrancescoMoca could you update the testDb so I can make some tests? Tnx

Comment: Sorry for now answering before but i think i solved my problem:
I am adding " while ( @class = 'Address' or (@class = 'Transaction' and height >=0 and height <=5000 )" at the end of the traverse.

Comment: Now I am using this query:
`select head, sum(valueTot) as valueTot, count(*),sum(miner) as minerCount from (SELECT *,traversedElement(0) as head from ( TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from (select * from Transaction where height >= 0 and height <= 5000) while ( @class = 'Address' or (@class = 'Transaction' and height >=0 and height <=5000 ))  )  where @class = 'Transaction'  ) group by head `
But it's really slow with a lot of transactions.
I tried to use an index like @Alessandro suggested but I don't think it helped. What can i do to be sure that is using the Transaction.height index? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi, if you update the shared test DB I'll make some testing

Comment: BTW, I'm trying with the current db (the one you linked before) and I'm having different results using this new query instead of the old one

Comment: Yeah, the last one gives me the results I was looking for.
The problem that with around 1M vertices is really slow, I updated my question, hope you can help :)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your query `select head, sum(valueTot) as valueTot, count(*),sum(miner) as minerCount from (SELECT *,traversedElement(0) as head from ( TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from (select * from Transaction where height >= 0 and height <= 5000) while ( @class = 'Address' or (@class = 'Transaction' and height >=0 and height <=5000 )) ) where @class = 'Transaction' ) group by head` on your updated DB. It's taking about 3seconds to me resulting 4756 items

Comment: what if you try with a larger one ? `select head, sum(valueTot) as valueTot, count(*) as numTx,sum(miner) as minerCount from (SELECT *,traversedElement(0) as head from ( TRAVERSE both('ValueTx') from (select * from Transaction where height >= 0 and height <= 110000 ) while ( @class = 'Address' or (@class = 'Transaction' and height >= 0 and height <= 110000 )) ) where @class = 'Transaction' ) group by head
`